# Karma - Load Files From Directories First

Tags: javascript, testing, karma-runner

My karma files config:

```
files: [
    ...
    app/scripts/**/*.js
    ...
],
```

I have 4 directories under `scripts` directory, and `app.js`.

I need the `app.js` to be loaded last (since it depends on other scripts).

Any way to ensure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negation like this:

```
files: [
    'app/scripts/**/!(app).js',
    'app/scripts/app.js'
],
```

This makes `app.js` to be loaded at the end.